# Mozilla Firefox implementation status page

Tags: firefox, web

Is there a page for Mozilla Firefox implementation status and what features are on implementation agenda, like http://www.chromestatus.com/features or http://status.modern.ie/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We normally refer people to caniuse but I think we should have a feature dashboard like the ones you mention:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1055074

Comment: Oh that would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla Firefox is working on this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.platform/2yih0-uJzcI